# How do I add unsigned 64 bit drivers to WDS

Tags: wds

Windows Deployment Services on 2008 R2.

I'm trying to add a 64 bit driver package. Dell provides the drivers but they are unsigned. WDS does not allow adding unsigned 64 bit drivers. Is it possible to override this requirement and add them anyway, or is there a simple way to sign these drivers myself?

To be clear, I'm not trying to inject drivers into the boot image, just have them available in the driver pool during installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your *only* option would be injecting the driver into the image [using dsim.exe with the /forceunsigned switch](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744355%28WS.10%29.aspx#AddDriverDISM).

Comment: Is it possible to add the driver while creating the image or can I only add it to the offline image?

Comment: To be honest I never tried creating an image with unsigned drivers preinstalled. Might work.