# Can I have virtio-win package on CentOS?

Tags: redhat, kvm-virtualization, virtio

In "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6. Virtualization Host Configuration and Guest Installation Guide" in chapter 10.1 "[Installing the KVM Windows para-virtualized drivers](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide/#sect-Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide-Para_virtualized_drivers-Installing_the_KVM_Windows_para_virtualized_drivers)" it says:

> The virtio-win package contains the para-virtualized block and network drivers for all supported Windows guest virtual machines. The virtio-win package can be found here [in RHN](https://rhn.redhat.com/rhn/software/packages/details/Overview.do?pid=602010)

Alas, RHN is a premium feature of Red Hat Enterprise Linux. Are virtio drivers available on CentOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can [download the drivers](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers) from the upstream KVM project.

If you want an installable `virtio-win` RPM package, similar to that provided by RHEL, then you can use the [virtio-win yum repository](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-windows-virtual-machines-using-virtio-drivers/index.html) provided by the Fedora Project.

Comment: Should be noted that only RHEL subscribers get access to the properly WHQL-signed drivers. While it's possible to install the vendor-signed drivers from the Fedora package, it's not possible to e.g. [import them into WDS](https://serverfault.com/questions/273809/how-do-i-add-unsigned-64-bit-drivers-to-wds).

Answer (score 2):

As @Michael Hampton pointed out, you can [download the drivers](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers) from the offsite. The RPM is just a wrapper around a set of .vfd and .iso files, containing the drivers, it doesn't do anything on the host besides copying those files so they are available. In short, you don't really need the RPM.